# Why does string and list make difference in UNICODE(utf-8)? How can '-' make Error?

Tags: python, unicode

```
>>> final=[]
>>> for a in range(65535):
        final.append([a,chr(a)])


>>> file=open('1.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
>>> file.write(str(final))
960881
>>> file.close()
>>> final=''
>>> for a in range(65535):
        final+='%d -------- %s'%(a,chr(a))


>>> file=open('2.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
>>> file.write(final)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    file.write(final)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 873642: surrogates not allowed
```

As you can see, 1.txt is saved. Why does saving the second 'file'(string) make error?

Comment: Perhaps the reason why you get an error is due to `\ud800` responding to  UTF-16 surrogate pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/D000-DFFF):

> Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646 do not assign actual characters to any of the code points in the D800–DFFF range — these code points only have meaning when used in surrogate pairs. Hence an individual code point from a surrogate pair does not represent a character, is invalid unless used in a surrogate pair, and

So I'd say `chr(0xd800)` already is invalid and I guess Python just doesn't check it for speed reasons. But the UTF-8 encoder does check it and complains.

The reason it works for the first file is that wrapping the string in a list and using `str` on that list leads to `repr`-ing the string:

```
>>> str( chr(0xd800) )
'\ud800'
>>> str([chr(0xd800)])
"['\\ud800']"
```

Note the double backslash in the list version. Instead of one "invalid character" `\ud800` it's the six valid characters `\`, `u`, `d`, `8`, `0` and `0`. And those can be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

The codepoints `U+D800` through `U+DFFF` are reserved for [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and can already be seen in the error message

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud800' in position 873642: surrogates not allowed

You can't write characters in that range. It's only used for UTF-16 to encode codepoints [outside the BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF) (i.e. > 65535).

Note that Unicode is **not** a 16-bit charset, so going up to 65535 is **not** enough. To print all the Unicode characters you need to print all the way up to [U+​10FFFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Code_point_planes_and_blocks) except the surrogate range. It's also easier to use UTF-32 for this instead

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what do you mean? The OP is printing characters in that range which is invalid

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of a good way how to get `UTF-16` to `UTF-8`, however you could probably apply this method to read file if you **DO NOT** require 100% accurate representation:

```
f = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
```

Comment: There is nothing about UTF-16 here.  Translating from UTF-16 to UTF-8 in Python is trivial, anyway; `utf16bytes.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8')`. Skipping the invalid characters is probably a good workaround in this case, but you are not even trying to explain what's wrong or how your workaround loses some data.

Comment: @tripleee does the above code not solve the problem or partially solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is primarily in the OP's understanding of the behavior; your answer does not attempt to explain it, so no, it doesn't solve the problem IMO; and the UTF-16 red herring is definitely capricious if not outright misleading.